# app.post is working but app.use isn't. Express Node

Tags: node.js, express, axios

When i use that code:

```
app.post("/something", (req, res) => {

});
```

everything is working correctly.
But when i use that:

```
import something from './something';
app.use("/something", something);
```

I get error: POST http://localhost:3000/something 404 (Not Found)
Why "/something" can be find while using app.post but with app.use cannot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Server.js (main server file).By using

```
app.post("/something", (req, res) => {

});
```

if you call **/something** then it show results.

---

But if you created another file and importing it like

```
import something from './something';
app.use("/something", something);
```

then your something.js must be like:

```
import express from 'express'
 var app = express.Router()
app.post("/", (req, res) => {

});
export default app
```

This will match '/something'
But if something.js is like

```
   import express from 'express'
 var app = express.Router()
app.post("/something", (req, res) => {

});
export default app
```

then it will match '/something/something'